# Why is Brock drawn with his eyes closed?

Tags: anime, pokemon

Brock seems to walk around with his [eyes perpetually closed](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:Brock_Season_1_settei.jpg). I've seen a bunch of fan-theories about why this is, including;

- To make him look wise (AKA "*[kitsune no me](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EyesAlwaysShut)*").
- It's coding for him being Korean, rather than Japanese.
- Because he's got X-Men style [hyperbeam eyes](https://i.chzbgr.com/full/7961762048/h56FC3D89/brock-used-hyper-beam-it-was-super-effective).
- That he's actually blind.
- Because [his tiny pupils](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mg_xJ8iYaJc) are sensitive to light
- etc.

Has there been any **definitive statement from the show's makers** as to why he's drawn like that, as opposed to the other characters who have their eyes open?

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNthZ7uUkkM - Maybe it's because his eyes are just plain scary to children

Comment: The idea that the art style used for Brock's eyes is meant to show him as being from a different ethnicity than Ash and many of the other characters seems very credible. Note that he also has a darker skin tone than Ash or Misty (although that could just be because he is tanned from hiking).

Comment: I think it's just an anime trope. Look at Gin from Bleach, or Shino from Kannagi. Sometimes characters are just drawn with their eyes nearly always shut.

Comment: @Showsni - I'm assuming there was a conscious decision made here. He's the only character who looks like this.

Comment: @Adamant - Characters with darker skin in anime are typically Mongolian but it's unheard-of to depict them with closed eyes if that's the case.

Comment: @Adamant One quote we do have from the creators of the anime is that they were worried people in America and the west would assume Brock was a racial stereotype, based on his eyes - that's why they dropped him for the Orange Islands arc and replaced him with Tracey. When they discovered people liked Brock and didn't assume that, they brought him back.

Comment: My gut feeling is that Ken Sugimori drew a tough guy with his eyes closed intended for just that one "scene" of you coming across him in the gym - note that his original overworld sprite seems to have open eyes. But the anime ran with the closed eyes design of the larger sprite. There's two questions we'd need to answer - from Ken, why his original design had closed eyes. And from the anime staff, why they kept the closed eyes for the rest of the time.

Comment: He just inherited this trait from his father. Also he's not the only character like that. The old man from Ep172 (JP counting) also has eyes like that.

Answer (score 3):

It's a trait he inherited from his father.

[image]

Everyone in his family is like that.
The dark skin is a consequence of working outside under the sun and getting tanned.

[image]

Likely they just copied his design from the game and rolled with it.

[image]

Comment: Lol. But why does his *father* have closed eyes?

Comment: Because *his* father had closed eyes

Comment: It's fathers all the way down.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - All the way back to close-eyed australopithecines